# Is it possible to tween orbit controls with three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When using the TWEEN function in three.js, I notice it is specifically for tweening objects.

I'm able to tween the camera position but I want to also tween the orbit control.
This would emulate following a target while the camera is on a dolly.

Currently the camera position is tweened with this code:

```
        var xTarget=0;
        var yTarget=0;
        var zTarget=0;

        function setupCamTween(xTarget,yTarget,zTarget){

        var update  = function(){
            camera.position.x = current.x;
            camera.position.y = current.y;
            camera.position.z = current.z;

        }   

        TWEEN.removeAll();

        var current = { x: myCameraX, y : myCameraY, z : myCameraZ };
        var target = { x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : zTarget};

        console.log("moving cam");

        var camTween = new TWEEN.Tween(current).to(target, 1000);
        camTween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut);


        camTween.start();



        camTween.onUpdate(function(){
            camera.position.x=current.x;
            camera.position.y=current.y;
            camera.position.z=current.z;


        });     
    }
setupCamTween(0,900,4000);
```

I then use this code to change the target on the orbit.

```
controls.target.set(0,myCameraY,2000);
controls.update();
```

So when I do this, the camera tweens to the location, then it jumps to the target controls point.

I want to get rid of the jumping when the orbit control is set.

So I created a function as follows to tween the orbit control:

```
    function orbitCam(){

        var update  = function(){
            controls.target.x=current.x;
            controls.target.y=current.y;
            controls.target.z=current.z;
        }
            //TWEEN.removeAll();

            var current = {x: myCameraX, y: myCameraY, z: myCameraZ };
            var target = {x: 0, y: 200, z: 0};

            var orbitTween = new TWEEN.Tween(current).to(target,2000);
            orbitTween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut);

    orbitTween.onUpdate(function(){
        controls.target.set.x=current.x;
        controls.target.set.y=current.y;
        controls.target.set.z=current.z;


    }); 

    }
```

When I call this function, it does nothing.
So I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to tween the setting of the target of the orbit control.
Any advice is appreciated.

I am calling controls update in the animation function.

```
    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        TWEEN.update();

        controls.update();

    }
```

I managed to get the following code to work. But unfortunately, I lose all orbit control after the target has been set.

```
    var xTarget=0;
    var yTarget=0;
    var zTarget=0;
    var tweenDuration=0;

    function setupCamTween(xTarget,yTarget,zTarget,tweenDuration){

    var update  = function(){
        camera.position.x = current_position.x;
        camera.position.y = current_position.y;
        camera.position.z = current_position.z;
        controls.target.x = current_target.x;
        controls.target.y = current_target.y;
        controls.target.z = current_target.z;

    }   

    //TWEEN.removeAll();

    var current_position = { x: myCameraX, y : myCameraY, z : myCameraZ };
    var target = { x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : zTarget};

    var current_target = { x: myCameraX, y : myCameraY, z : myCameraZ };
    var new_target = {x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : zTarget};

    console.log("moving cam");

    var camTween = new TWEEN.Tween(current_position).to(target, tweenDuration);
    camTween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut);  
    camTween.start();

    var targetTween = new TWEEN.Tween(current_target).to(new_target, tweenDuration);
    targetTween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut);   
    targetTween.start();

    camTween.onUpdate(function(){
    camera.position.x=current_position.x;
    camera.position.y=current_position.y;
    camera.position.z=current_position.z;


}); 

    targetTween.onUpdate(function(){
    controls.target.x = controls.object.position.x;
    controls.target.y = controls.object.position.y;
    controls.target.z = controls.object.position.z;
    controls.target.x = current_target.x;
    controls.target.y = current_target.y;
    controls.target.z = current_target.z;

});


}
```

Comment: I feel your pain (as in my attempts at something similar at [jsfiddle.net/gpolyn/bpo7t7f6](https://jsfiddle.net/gpolyn/bpo7t7f6).) Are you calling `controls.update` in your new code? Don't you need to?

Comment: Yes i am.  I updated my question to show that.  I'm wondering if I'm going about it all wrong.  maybe a simple camera rotation will do or target but I can't get that to work either.

Comment: I'm interested in a fix for this, too. I expect, however, that a fix may have to do with getting the issue of target re-setting worked out, so that it is smoother.

Comment: You need to start the second tween as well, I think `orbitTween.start()` might work

Answer (score 4):

I simplified the code and now it works.
The issue was that the code was setting the camera position z value to the controls target z.  This for some reason, broke the orbit control.

Here is the simplified version for panning the camera using a tween.  The function in my code is called on a mouse down event.

```
        var xTarget=0;
        var yTarget=0;
        var zTarget=0;
        var tweenDuration=0;

        function panCam(xTarget,yTarget,zTarget,tweenDuration){

          TWEEN.removeAll();

          var camNewPosition= { x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : zTarget};
          var targetNewPos = {x : xTarget, y : yTarget, z : 0};

          var camTween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to(camNewPosition, tweenDuration).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();
          var targetTween = new TWEEN.Tween(controls.target).to(targetNewPos, tweenDuration).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut).start();
    }

        function animate() { //call this function at the beginning

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            TWEEN.update();

            controls.update();


        }
panCam(500,200,4000,1000);  //This pans the camera to the an x of 500, y of 200 and a z of 4000 with a duration of 1 second.
```

Comment: Really appreciate the share! This worked for me as well. Thanks